# Adjust plotly output height to box with dynamic height in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

In the `shiny` app below I have a box which height depends on the number of shiny widgets it includes and a plot. I would like the box height to somehow saved every time it changes and be passed to the plot in order to have the same height always.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly) 
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
                  dashboardSidebar(
                    # Copy the line below to make a set of radio buttons
                    radioButtons("radio1", label = h3("Radio buttons"),
                                 choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2), 
                                 selected = 1)
                  ),
                  dashboardBody(
                    fluidRow(
                      column(4,
                             box(
                               # Copy the line below to make a set of radio buttons
                               radioButtons("radio2", label = h3("Radio buttons"),
                                            choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
                                            selected = 1),
                               uiOutput("rd3")
                             )),
                     plotlyOutput("t2")
                    )
                  )
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$rd3<-renderUI({
    if(input$radio1==1){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else{
      radioButtons("radio3", label = h3("Radio buttons"),
                   choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
                   selected = 1)
    }
  })
    output$t2<-renderPlotly(
      fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
      
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works based on `spsComps::heightMatcher`.
However, I needed to trigger a resize event via `shinyjs` to avoid the plot height getting out of sync after a few clicks, which I think should not be necessary (also makes it quite slow).

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
library(spsComps)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(# Copy the line below to make a set of radio buttons
    radioButtons(
      "radio1",
      label = h3("Radio buttons"),
      choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2),
      selected = 1
    )),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
             box(
               id = "box_1",
               # Copy the line below to make a set of radio buttons
               radioButtons(
                 "radio2",
                 label = h3("Radio buttons"),
                 choices = list(
                   "Choice 1" = 1,
                   "Choice 2" = 2,
                   "Choice 3" = 3
                 ),
                 selected = 1
               ),
               uiOutput("rd3")
             )),
      box(id = "box_2", plotlyOutput("t2", height = "100%")),
      spsComps::heightMatcher("box_2", "box_1")
    )
  )
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$radio1, {
    shinyjs::runjs("$(window).trigger('resize');")
  })
  
  output$rd3 <- renderUI({
    if (input$radio1 == 1) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      radioButtons(
        "radio3",
        label = h3("Radio buttons"),
        choices = list(
          "Choice 1" = 1,
          "Choice 2" = 2,
          "Choice 3" = 3
        ),
        selected = 1
      )
    }
  })
  
  output$t2 <- renderPlotly({fig <-
                              plot_ly(
                                data = iris,
                                x = ~ Sepal.Length,
                                y = ~ Petal.Length
                              )})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @lz100 can you please have a look at this (without using `shinyjs`)?

Comment: from what I can see even if the 2 boxes have now always the same height the plot does not follow so what if I remove the box of the plot and pass the box of the shiny widget directly to the plot?

Comment: i dont see how it works if I remove "box_2". I do not even see "box_1"now